Why does build_super_image use --metadata-slots 3
When building a super image with lpmake via build_super_image.py that has
ab_update=true, the --metadata-slots flag is given 3 as its value.
From https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/main/tools/releasetools/build_super_image.py#87
if ab_update and retrofit:
  cmd += ["--metadata-slots", "2"]
elif ab_update:
  cmd += ["--metadata-slots", "3"]
else:
  cmd += ["--metadata-slots", "2"]

Other parts of AOSP indicate that an A/B device should have 2 slots.
From https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/refs/heads/main/partition_tools/

-s,--metadata-slots - The number of slots available for storing metadata. This should match the number of update slots on the device, 2 for A/B devices and 1 for non-A/B.

From https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/fs_mgr/liblp/include/liblp/metadata_format.h
/* 44: Number of copies of the metadata to keep. For A/B devices, this
 * will be 2. For an A/B/C device, it would be 3, et cetera. For Non-A/B
 * it will be 1. A backup copy of each slot is kept, so if this is "2",
 * there will be four copies total.
 */
uint32_t metadata_slot_count;

AFAIK there are no Android A/B/C devices, am I missing something or is build_super_image.py doing this incorrectly?
